# ¿Cómo hacer un "PUT" o "PATCH en Djago Rest Framework?

Tags: django, webservice, aplicación-web, djangorestframework

Hace unas semanas cree una `API Rest` para una Web con `DRF`, pero he tenido problemas para realizar las consultas desde la página, y aunque ya he hecho `"GET"`, aún no puedo hacer los `"POST", "PUT" o "PATCH"`.

La función que tengo para el `"PUT"` es:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "PUT",
  url: "/petitions/"+petition+"/",
  data: {pattern: 'N'} ,

  success: function(data) {
    $('#savechange1').modal('toggle'); 
  }
});
```

Sin embargo al ejecutarla me devuelve:

> jquery.min.js:4 PUT http://192.168.0.19:9000/petitions/2/ 403 (Forbidden)
>   send    @   jquery.min.js:4
>   ajax    @   jquery.min.js:4
>   (anonymous) @   tesis-principal.js:151
>   dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:3
>   q.handle    @   jquery.min.js:3

Se supone que el problema radicaría en tema de permisos, pero ya estoy logeado y no sé cómo agregar los permisos particulares en el `"PUT"`.
En el settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',

    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10}
```

Los archivos de la app son:

**permissions.py:**

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the snippet.
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

**serializers.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Petitions
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    highlight = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='petitions-highlight', format='html')

    class Meta:
        model = Petitions
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'highlight', 'owner',
                  'Patients', 'date','time', 'state', 'pattern', 'expert', 'test_order', 'visible')
```

**views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list` and `detail` actions.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class PetitionsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.

    Additionally we also provide an extra `highlight` action.
    """
    queryset = Petitions.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PetSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    @detail_route(renderer_classes=[renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer])
    def highlight(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        petitions = self.get_object()
        return Response(petitions.highlighted)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)


@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'users': reverse('user-list', request=request, format=format),
        'petitions': reverse('petitions-list', request=request, format=format)
    })


class PeticionesHighlight(generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Petitions.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = (renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        petitions = self.get_object()
        return Response(petitions.highlighted)

    def put(self, request, pk):
        model = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = PetSerializer(model, data=request.data, partial=True) 
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonReponse(code=201, data=serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(code=400, data="wrong parameters")
```

Comment: muestra la implementacion de tu api

Comment: No sé si servirá, es mi primera pregunta y no sé cómo editarla bien

Comment: Te recomiendo seguir el [tour] y leer las reglas de [ask]

Comment: Gracias por la edición, leeré las intrucciones y espero hacerlo bien la próxima vez. Nuevamente, muchas gracias.